# Laravel 5.2: extracting nested collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections, laravel-5

I am working on Laravel 5.2 application. I'm having an issue in extracting the nested collection from the parent collection. I'm trying to get all the posts from the users whom I am following like this:

```
$posts = \Auth::user()->following()->get()->each(function($following){
    return $following->posts;
});
```

But it is returning me a collection of the users I am following and the posts collection is nested in this collection, such that:

```
[
    {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "username": "john",
    "email": "johny@example.com", 
    "created_at": "2016-03-08 11:06:45",
    "updated_at": "2016-03-08 11:06:45",
    "pivot": {
        "follower_id": 1,
         "followee_id": 2
    },
    "posts": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "user_id": 2,
            "title": "Post title 1",
            "created_at": "2016-03-08 11:09:22",
            "updated_at": "2016-03-08 11:09:22"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "user_id": 2,
            "title": "Post title 2",
            "created_at": "2016-03-09 08:04:18",
            "updated_at": "2016-03-09 08:04:18"
        }
        ]
    }
]
```

How can I get all the posts from the all of the users I'm following as a collection?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
$posts = [];
\Auth::user()->following()->get()->each(function($following) use(&$posts){
    array_push($posts, $following->posts)
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is filtering all the posts well but the posts are not becoming an instance of App\Post.